# Memory leak in google maps api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an activity that just toggles between a map (google android v2 api) and an image. I use MapFragment. 
For some reason even though i try to do map.clear(), it still holds on to the memory. 
As, you can see, every time the map is shown, I have a new instance of maps.z.a in the memory map. 
How do it clear these? I have tried manually running System.gc() as well.

```
Class Name                                                   | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap | Percentage
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                             |              |               |           
class android.content.res.Resources @ 0x41267910 System Class|           40 |     8,526,400 |     39.29%
android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0x421b0620                         |           48 |     5,760,064 |     26.54%
android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0x415a33e0                         |           48 |     1,127,600 |      5.20%
maps.as.aw @ 0x434a6750                                      |          160 |       278,072 |      1.28%
maps.p.c @ 0x421b4110                                        |           32 |       211,040 |      0.97%
maps.z.a @ 0x4218f698                                        |          152 |       205,864 |      0.95%
maps.z.a @ 0x421f69a8                                        |          152 |       205,256 |      0.95%
maps.z.a @ 0x4222f5c8                                        |          152 |       205,256 |      0.95%
maps.z.a @ 0x4366fb20                                        |          152 |       205,256 |      0.95%
android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0x41feb6e0                         |           48 |       160,064 |      0.74%
java.util.zip.ZipFile @ 0x42155b40                           |           32 |       139,704 |      0.64%
maps.as.q @ 0x41f35e30                                       |           80 |       131,536 |      0.61%
maps.as.q @ 0x421dcad8                                       |           80 |       131,536 |      0.61%
maps.as.q @ 0x434e7d90                                       |           80 |       131,536 |      0.61%
maps.as.q @ 0x435ccc40                                       |           80 |       131,536 |      0.61%
maps.as.aw @ 0x420c5e90                                      |          160 |       127,944 |      0.59%
class android.text.Html$HtmlParser @ 0x41e18f98 System Class |            8 |       126,632 |      0.58%
maps.as.aw @ 0x435bc4e0                                      |          160 |       111,624 |      0.51%
android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0x415e6708                         |           48 |       100,304 |      0.46%
class libcore.icu.TimeZones @ 0x4123d1e8 System Class        |           40 |        90,080 |      0.42%
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Code Segments:

Adding to View

> ```
> frag = MapFragment.newInstance();
> // Add the MapFragment to the view
> FragmentTransaction ft = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
> ft.add(this.getId(), frag).commit();
> ```

Removing from View

> ```
> FragmentTransaction ft = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
> ft.remove(frag).commit();
> ```

Comment: Make sure that you are on the latest version of the Play Services SDK, both in terms of what you have downloaded from the SDK Manager and in terms of what copy of that library project is being used by your app.

Comment: I have the latest google play services sdk (7) pointed from this app.

Comment: Then I suggest that you create a reproducible test case (complete project source code and steps to follow), upload it somewhere, and file an issue on the Maps issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list I have also adjusted your tags to be ones that the Maps team is supposed to be monitoring (https://developers.google.com/maps/forum/).

Comment: Are you sure it's maps and not you holding onto a Context somewhere? What is the path to the GC root from maps.z.a ? Also, System.gc() is a not a fix for a memory leak. The Garbage Collector cannot collect objects with things still referencing them, that's why it's a leak.

Comment: Can you put relevant parts of the code in your question?

Comment: added code segments that i used to add the fragment to the view and removing it.